# assert of null or undefined is not picked up on in nested function

Tags: typescript

I have this function:

```
function assertNonNullish<TValue>(
  value: TValue,
  error?: Error
): asserts value is NonNullable<TValue> {
  if (value === null || value === undefined) {
    error ??= new Error("Something does not exist");
    throw error;
  }
}
```

This is supposed to check if something is not null nor undefined. If I use this function typescript also knows that something is not null nor undefined.

However when I use this function in another function like so:

```
function has_email() {
  const email = localStorage.getItem('email')
  assertNonNullish(email, new Error("email does not exist"));
}
```

and then use the has_email function to check the argument of another function:

```
function print_email(email: string) {
  console.log(email);
}

has_email() // Throws if email is not available but ts doesn't pick up on this
const email = localStorage.getItem('email')

print_email(email)
```

It seems like TypeScript can not figure out that running `has_email()` would be the same as `assertNonNullish(localStorage.getItem('email'))`

Is there any way to let TypeScript know? I would like to do it this way because I have to check state which has to be loaded from indexDB and I first have to await that.

Comment: I am awaiting the has_id function.

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, **as plain text in the body of your post**. Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/Nr5L0w) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Without a reproducible example I can't say for certain, but the general issue is likely that the effects of [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) do not cross function boundaries; it's a general limitation that's essentially impossible to solve "correctly", see [ms/TS#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).  So any narrowing that goes on inside `has_id()` will not be seen by the caller.  As for "letting TS know" that depends strongly on your example code and might require refactoring.

Comment: Ok thanks that answered my question. Thanks for the helpfull link explaining it.

Comment: I'd be happy to write up an answer explaining.  Could you please [edit] your question to provide the requested example so that future readers have a good q/a pair to consult?

Comment: @jcalz I edited the question. Is this ok?

Comment: Your example code compiles with no errors; presumably your issue is with using `has_email()`, but you haven't shown that.  I also don't see why `has_email()` is `async`.  Could you address those?

Comment: @jcalz ok how about now? I think this is what you were after. Do keep in mind that in my actual code it is more complicated to get the what is here the email and there are also async functions involved.

Comment: Okay so now I can see that this is definitely impossible, even theoretically.  There's no guarantee in the type system that two calls to `localStorage.getItem('email')` will produce identical results.  I'm not even sure that this is something we can be sure about unless we know some pretty fiddly details of how `localStorage` is implemented.  If you change it so that there's a single call to `getItem()` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7O6PN) then it's at least theoretically possible, but not something the compiler can feasibly track as per ms/TS#9998.

Comment: So anything you do here will have to be a complete refactoring like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nr5J5w) or you'll need to use type assertions like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9E81N).  Neither way is ideal for you (one way changes your procedure, the other loses type safety) but it is what is is.  Does that explain it enough for me to write up an answer?

Comment: @jcalz Yes this explains it enough for you to write up an answer. Thanks for all the comments. As for me I now just went with something like [your this](https://tsplay.dev/Nr5J5w) but what you suggested is better I think so I will switch to that. Also I just used local storage to make the example self contained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler is, unfortunately, unable to track what's going on in your code well enough to provide the typings you expect.  Your example code is currently making two separate calls of the form

```
const email1 = localStorage.getItem('email');
const email2 = localStorage.getItem('email');
```

And it is your expectation that the value of `email1` and `email2` will be the same, and thus they should have the same type (e.g., if `email1` is not nullish then neither is `email2`). But TypeScript doesn't have a great way to encode such an expectation; checking the type of `email1` won't cause the compiler to conclude anything whatsoever about subsequent behavior of  `localStorage.getItem()`.  And in fact I'm not sure you should conclude much either; if the two calls are in the same thread and there is no intervening storage mutation then maybe you can say that the second call will return the same value as the first.  But in general there's no such guarantee.

---

Let's remove that problem by having a single call to `localStorage.getItem('email')` and a single `const` variable named `email` whose value will therefore always be the same no matter when you check it:

```
const email: string | null = localStorage.getItem('email');

function has_email() {
  assertNonNullish(email, new Error("email does not exist"));
}

has_email();
```

Now it is absolutely 100% guaranteed that any code that runs after `has_email()` will have access to a non-null `email` variable.  But, the compiler still doesn't see it:

```
email.toUpperCase(); // error! Object is possibly null
```

Why not?

---

This is a general limitation of TypeScript, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998). When you check or assert the type of some value so as to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) its apparent type, the compiler uses [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to keep track of where and when such a narrowing should apply.  But this analysis only works inside a single function scope.  It does not cross function boundaries.  That means any narrowing inside a function will be inaccessible from outside, and vice versa.  In our particular example, the narrowing of `email` that occurs inside the body of `has_email()` has no effect on any code outside, and we get an error.

This limitation can't be easily remedied. As a human being I can imagine running the above code twice, once assuming the `email` variable of type `string | null` is a `string`, and another time assuming it is `null`. In the former case everything is fine, and in the latter case you never reach any problematic line.  For a union of two members and a `has_email()` function that's called once, this is easy enough to do.  But it just doesn't scale. Most functions are called multiple times, and if you have multiple union-typed variables you would need to simulate every possible combination of values for every function call.  I once suggested at [microsoft/TypeScript#25051](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051) that you could ask for this behavior on an opt-in basis (e.g., "please only do this kind of analysis for the `email` variable), but it was declined; this sort of thing needs to happen automatically or not at all.

---

There's also no concept of an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) or [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) where the value whose type you are narrowing is not one of the parameters to the function (or the `this` context of a method).  You can't annotate `has_email(): asserts email is string`, since `email` is not one of the parameters to `has_email()`. So again, there's no way to tell the compiler that `has_email()` has any implications on the state of `email`.

---

For these reasons, you need to work around it.

You can't keep your algorithm the same  without losing some type safety.  You can suppress the error with [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
// assertion 
email!.toUpperCase(); // okay
```

but that suppresses the error even if you forget to call `has_email()` first.

Or, if you care more about type safety guarantees than about your particular algorithm, you could refactor.  Currently you are assigning `email` in one place and then checking it with `has_email()` in another place, and leaving open the possibility that you can access `email` where it could be `null`.  Instead, we can write a version where the assignment and type guarding happens together:

```
function getDefiniteEmail(): string {
  const email = localStorage.getItem('email');
  assertNonNullish(email);
  return email;
}

const email = getDefiniteEmail();
email.toUpperCase(); // okay
```

Now when you call `getDefiniteEmail()` you know you will get a `string` back and not `null`; it's already been checked!  This sidesteps the entire problem of control flow analysis crossing function boundaries, because we've encoded the state we care about in the return type of `getDefiniteEmail()`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.7.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJKiSwLICSYMA9lFAJYBGGyBhRJJAZgK7B4AFyZ1gSEIwgAnYQDlx8-hgxMoACwA8AFQBqmfhAB8ACm48SAN0MQAXEn22ANBcuyZdGQH4HAURlPGTckAEoHKShZYSgkGwwjJHUkRWBlVRA2CF0DBJM8EJImXiRTeMSAXirSFQwkAB96uNskKoqkQQATCF4mYAhO0ILiSx4PLyRvb3b+gHckAKDTACIAZTpIYQ0+gHMkTrpoUjphJAgAD3VhZdCAbkKeLc958Zl7kcsAXxDvrg+kARCUTiJAaKQAfQgYBATAwpiGnFGSHg4igpyhMLq7QwdHQGFWwi8IB2EAAdCThFRhFDTAByDGw2mhB6RaKpdJqTSmBkYZykCDzRZeFY8-aHWLAE5nS5om53H5EEJgqCQ6Gw+FIAD0mscGmesWKZzVdWSktOIBssMy7CQLH4pxiYugwFppxgTHgAGsOjAkCCtuoQijgGijZjWkgcXiCUSSeSIJTqWA6TymSEeaTCQBVGAwWQAYSkEHh7xIv0VIzI0DgiF1EC8CY9mAwAE8AAoMZhZABC9sUwh0MgQnoGABEjDo6ABOGcADmGlkBIjEElZcnZtXU2iceTMD3K9kcuSMrn+JFevgWgS8IXCkmkcliB6SsQ3GSyOVsxgXo0NZRabQ1KoDRNM+gFdD0fQDAiDznteMiTNM-KCvBKzrJs2zAHsBxHGa0pXDcpZIkgTx0C88FEV8Cp-JYwahjyDhojIuwNEBWKRrimAxkOcYUlSNL0saTKUQCgjLiCyqqpiGqIqMa4KEom5cjyfJzFeSzLKKOESlKFwEaE8r-OW-ySTyJbpsamZ0DmeYyIWUQllqOqvAAhEgADyLAAFYQCIL5IPQjCsK2bEVpY2r3lEcgrkgFmYi5Vk2QWRaORFdCeiALYVhYxkWFWFC1gASj0CCEjIAw-nwYnAquD4KWkSnbseJjmGezR5A4O4ng8F7+PBt4RHVT4tMkb4YNa2RdfksmWH+YHVMAtQge1lTVBBvT9IMlWjK8iEzAK6nCmsGwJph2Hisc6IytchnESRepkWcFEPL8VH-EuNVIBSo6QcATDUn4xrwoxwjMVh20kHR6LGhGUZcWVxJknxSYpkJt1yXVY1btyxro5Y5XCPwMgSDyInGbRqLQ+G7Tfb9-0QID0l42GsKJbmyUOYZOUVp8QA)